# Show the sum of an event per day by user in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I want to be able to show the sum of an event (let's say clicks) per day but broken down by user type. The results I'm looking for will look like this:

| User Role | 01/01 | 01/02 | 01/03 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Guest | 500 | 450 | 348 | 55 |
| Admin | 220 | 200 | 150 | 75 |

Here is my initial start but I'm unsure how to do the pivots on this to produce a table and visual chart

`earliest=-30d index=* role=Guest OR role=Admin | count clicks as clickCount | ...`

I'm unsure on how to both only count by day but then also only count by role to render them as shown above. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: it seems like it would be easier to have the role as columns and the days as rows. Then you could use `| timechart span=1d count by role as "User Role"`

Comment: @MadsHansen while that doesn't actually answer the question it did indeed allow me to produce the data I was looking for. So maybe offer it as a possible solution and until I get a concrete answer to the one above I'll accept it

Comment: You can then `transpose` to almost give you what you want, but column headers won't have useful labels. Rather than try to figure out how to customize the `header_field`, I think I found a better way and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `timechart` by day and then `untable`, convert the `_time` into a `day` field with formatted mm/dd value, and then construct an `xyseries` with the rows as columns and the `day` as the header:

```
| timechart span=1d count by role as "User Role" 
| untable _time name value 
| eval day=strftime(_time, "%m/%d")  
| xyseries name day value
```